# Metric of a sequence (triangle inequality)

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, triangle-inequality

Define the function $d:X^w \times X^w \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{equation*}
    d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } x = y \\ \frac{1}{n} \text{ if } x\not =y \text{ and } n \text{ is the first index where } x_n\not = y_n
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Prove that $d$ is a metric on $X^w$.

I am having a bit of trouble proving the triangle inequality for this metric.  Here is what I have done, but I am not certain whether my argument is solid.  Here is what I have:

Let $x,y,z \in X^w$.  If $x=z$, then $d(x,z) = 0 \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. Suppose that $x \ne z$, where $d(x,z) = \frac{1}{k}$.  Consider $d(x,y)$.  There are two cases to consider, $m \leq k$ or $m > k$.  If $d(x,y) = \frac{1}{m}$ where $m \leq k$.  Then $\frac{1}{k} \leq \frac{1}{m}$ and we have
$$d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z).$$
If $d(x,y) = \frac{1}{m}$ where $m > k$. In this case, we must have $d(y,z) = \frac{1}{k}$, so that
$$d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z).$$

Is my argument correct?

Comment: $d$ is not properly defined. There may be many indicies $n$ with $x_n\neq y_n$.

Comment: should be the first index where they are different.  I will correct, thank you

Comment: How do you conclude that $d(y,z)$ must be $\frac  1 k$? That is not correct.

Comment: can you perhaps give an example where that would not be the case?

Comment: Ok, but $d(x,z)$ differ at position 3 and $d(x,y)$ is different at position 2, but $2 \leq 3$.  I am saying that if $d(x,y)$ is different at position $m > 3$, then $d(y,z)$ is also different at 3.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your proof is correct. It just requires some details.